# Element height in jquery mobile app: what unit to use?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile, responsive-design

I'm building a phonegap app in jquery mobile and need to set heights on some page elements. What is the best unit to use? I expect that it is not pixels, and possibly is percentages, but I'm having trouble finding an authoritative answer.

Answer (score 0):

rem unit is the best for mobile. Check this http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem for more info

Comment: You mean I should set html element size with rem? That article talks about fonts, which is not what I am asking.

Comment: Rem keeps the dimensions in a proportional size in any size for paddings and margins, not only fonts

Comment: Is a a good measure to apply for html5 apps (jquery mobile use this features)